# make array from MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry for a slight duplication of Q but I think the previous answers are now depreciated (I've seen that in PHP 5.3 you need you use MySQLi_fetch_array())

I'm using jpgraph and trying to pull my data from a MySQL database.  I have the following code which pulls the figures I need and when I echo the result it spits out the answers one by one no problem but it won't then put it into an array.

I'm trying to replace a line which is

```
$ydata = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);


//query
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT( 'Week ', WEEK( TimeofCompletion ) , ' ', YEAR( TimeofCompletion ) ) AS Week, Count( * ) AS VolumeOfAnswers
FROM table01
GROUP BY WEEK( TimeofCompletion ) , YEAR( TimeofCompletion ) 
ORDER BY TimeofCompletion";

$ydata = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
// Create a temporary array
 $temp = array();

 $temp[] = "".$row['VolumeOfAnswers']."";
$ydata = '['. implode(', ', $temp) . ']';   
}
```

Any suggestions how I would get the output by row into an array?

Regards
Maudise

Answer (score 0):

```
 $temp[] = "".$row['VolumeOfAnswers'].""; //what this suppose to do?
```

i assume you want quotes around i would add single quote inside

```
 $temp[] = "'".$row['VolumeOfAnswers']."'";
```

otherwise you dont need double quotes at all so i would remove them. After that your array will hold the values from the database.

according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) **mysql_fetch_array** is deprecated and you should be using PDO or MySQLi. But if you still want to use it, i would suggest using **mysql_fetch_assoc** instead.

**Now about the question:**

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  // Create a temporary array
  $temp = array();

  $temp[] = "".$row['VolumeOfAnswers']."";
  //why is this here? should be outside of while loop shouldnt it?
  $ydata = '['. implode(', ', $temp) . ']';   
 }
```

your $ydata always gets overwritten and holds only the last element of **$temp** array. Either move $ydata outside of while loop or use `array_merge($ydata, $temp);`

Comment: hi, for some reason it's telling me the array is empty?  Other errors I've had are that it can't define a min/max value which means I think it's reading it as string variables rather than numerical.  Any ideas?